# re-resolving data upon query parameter change?

Tags: angular, typescript

In my angular 2 projects, I wasn't able to reload the page by navigating to the same URL but with different query params. I am using **resolve** to pre-fetch data upon loading the page.

I am trying to get the resolver to re-fetch the data when there's URL (query param) change. How do I do this?

Answer (score 30):

Now you can with this in your route config:

```
{
  path: '',
  resolve: {
    data : DataResolver,
  },
  runGuardsAndResolvers: 'paramsOrQueryParamsChange',
  component: MainComponent
}
```

Passing the 'paramsOrQueryParamsChange' in your route config will trigger the `DataResolver` at each params or queryParams change.
you can get the resolvers data in your `MainComponent` like this:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.activatedRoute.data.subscribe((resolversData) => {
     // is now triggered at each queryParams change
  })
}
```

[see the doc for more info](https://angular.io/api/router/Routes)

Comment: I appreciate that you posted a link to the doc for more info, but can you provide some context for that link.

Comment: for other options, check https://angular.io/api/router/RunGuardsAndResolvers

Comment: When i tried the same, I am only getting data subscription once. The subsequent calls do not pass event to data

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't get changed queryParam. I don't know if this helps you but here is my answer.

```
construtor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

ngOnInit() {

  this.route.snapshot.queryParams['something'];//when you snapshot and navigate to same url you can't get new query params, only for first initialization

  // to get new queryparams or url params also you need subscribe (for same url navigation)

  this.route.queryParams.subscribe({
      (queryParams: Params) => {
          this.yourParam = queryParams['something'];  
      }
   })
}
```

I think you are using snapshot instead of Observable queryParams thats why.